# Why won't my Drag and Drop function not work?

Tags: javascript

I've been trying for two hours to get this simple Drag and Drop to work. It's probably gonna be something simple like missing a bracket.

```html
<div id="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="border: solid 1px red; width:604px; height:453px; padding:20px;" > </div>
 
<img id="drag" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" style="width:500px; height:400px;" src="https://live.staticflickr.com/4029/4687704358_a99633e0c7_z.jpg" ></img>
 
 
 
 

<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
 ev.preventDefault();
}
 
function drag(ev) {
 ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}
 
 
function drop(ev) {
 ev.preventDefault();
 var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
 ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementByID(data));
}
</script>
```

Comment: The function is called [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). Capitalisation matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo: `document.getElementByID(data)` should be `document.getElementById(data)`, note the lowercase `d` in `Id`